# Automatic variable escaper for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, escaping, xss, zend-view

Can you recommend any good solution for automatic view variable escaping for Zend Framework 1.x?

I have tried so far:

- [ZF2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) implementation; looks like it does not escape variables syntax like this: `$this->var->object()->string`
- [gnix-view](https://github.com/chikaram/gnix-view), very nice, but has a nasty recursion bug
- custom solutions based on `view streams`, similar to [Rob Allen's escaper](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-view-stream-with-zend_view/), but parsing syntax with regex always fails
- Twig (no good support for view helpers and layout)

Comment: Would you mind to leave a comment when downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i would think to make an automatic escaper i would create a ZF plugin that run in `postDispatch` :

**postDispatch() is called after an action is dispatched by the dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior. By altering the request and resetting its dispatched flag (via Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract::setDispatched(false)), a new action may be specified for dispatching.** [source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

mybe some use of htmlprifier would be a smart job :)

```
class Automatic_Escaper extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{
   public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $htmlpurifier = Zend_Registry::get('purifier');
        $safe = $htmlpurifier->purify($response);
        return $this->setResponse($safe);
    }
}
```

I hope I explained my idea regardless of the status  the sample above .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
/**
 * Purifies all data passed to view
 *
 * @author miholeus
 */
class HTMLPurifier_View extends Zend_View {
    protected $_vars = array();

    public function __set($key, $val)
    {

        if(is_string($val)) {
            $purified = $this->escape($val);
        } elseif(is_array($val)) {
            $purified = array_map(array($this, 'traverseSingle'), $val);
        } else { // other types: integers, bools, objects
            $purified = $this->traverseSingle($val);
        }

        $this->_vars[$key] = array(
            'raw' => $val,
            'purified' => $purified
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRaw($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->_vars[$key])) {
            return $this->_vars[$key]['raw'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->_vars[$key])) {
            return $this->_vars[$key]['purified'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private function traverseSingle($element)
    {
        if(is_object($element)) {
            $reflect = new ReflectionObject($element);
            foreach ($reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $prop) {
              $element->{$prop->getName()} = $this->escape($element->{$prop->getName()});
            }
            return $element;
        } else {
            return $this->escape($element);
        }
    }
}
```

All you need to do is to set it as your view in bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks. That's simple yet effective. I'm not sure about speed (reflection+loop), but for better memory management you may use lazy escaping in `__get` instead of `__set`.